# Find multiple values in multiple files using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have 3 files. Each file contains specific values. For exemple :

```
File 1 = bla bla bla foo bla bla bla
File 2 = bla bla fii bla bla bla foo
File 3 = bla bla bla bla bla fii bla
```

In notepad++, I want to find 'foo' and 'fii' values in all the different files i have.
I have search on google and i have found an expression, i tried this one  `(foo)|(fii)`  but it does not work.

Anyone knows if it's possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

That regular expression works for me, even when finding across multiple files.  In your Find dialog box, make sure you have "Regular Expression" checked under "Search Mode".  Without that, it will evaluate your search text as a normal string.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried again, and it doesn't work for me. I'll post a screen shot

Answer (score -2):

You need to do it with Regular Expression option checked, and without the () Just
foo|fii

I use it all the time and it works.

Comment: I'm not sure, but that's the way it works for me using Regular Expression option and without the (). Hope it also waorks for you!